# *ngFor and *ngForOf isn't work when I use async pipe

Tags: html, angular, angular11

I try to do everything change to in or change only *ngFor and it doesn't work
it show that problem

I am using NGRX Observable and values shown me on STORE dev tool but on my component isn't

How can I fix that issue?

```
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let swimsuit of swimsuits$ | async">
                <div *ngForOf="let swimsuitItem of swimsuit">
                    {{swimsuitItem.shirt}}
                    {{swimsuitItem.pants}}
                    {{swimsuitItem.lower}}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

error

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOfOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I use that documentation
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NgForOf]` is a directive used internally by `*ngFor`

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="swimsuits$ | async">
   <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

Is similar to:

```html
<li *ngFor="let swimsuit of swimsuits$ | async">...</li>
```

Without knowing the structure of your data, I'm assuming can simply do:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let swimsuit of swimsuits$ | async">
        {{swimsuit.shirt}}
        {{swimsuit.pants}}
        {{swimsuit.lower}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you add an example JSON model to your question, I'd be happy to update my answer to help you further.